# how can I merge two text files together

Tags: text-processing, join

I have a text file like this

```
sp|QBWMM1-2|PDCI_Mouse(741-770) 8864=mil (25/2.20/2.50)
sp|Pm345|Hisf_Mouse(613-640) 776=mil (25/2.20/2.50)
sp|P0065-2|Hila_Mouse(344-393)6543=mil (25/2.20/2.50)
sp|Q90081|Rira_Mouse(47-72) 7365=mil (25/2.20/2.50)
sp|QQQQQ1|Ubs_Mouse(162-190) 22=mil (25/2.20/2.50)
```

I have another text file like this

```
sp|QBWMM1-2|PDCI_Mouse complex subunit alpha OS=Mouse OX=90009 PE=1 SV=1
sp|Pm345|Hisf_Mouse Heat shock 70 kDa protein 1A OS=Mouse OX=90009 PE=1 SV=1
sp|O15012|SCCC_Mouse Protein transport protein Sec16A OS=MOUSE OX=90009 PE=1 SV=4
sp|P0065-2|Hila_Mouse Filamin-A OS=MOUSE OX=90009 PE=1 SV=4
sp|Q90081|Rira_Mouse Alpha-actin OS=Mouse OX=90009 PE=1 SV=2
sp|QQQQQ1|Ubs_Mouse Tubulin alpha8 chain OS=Mouse OX=90009 PE=1 SV=1
sp|QQQQQ2|Ubs_Mouse Plasta-3 OS=Mouse OX=90009 PE=1 SV=4
```

I want to merge them together keep the similar part and put the rest together. So for example, in text 1 and text 2, the following are similar:

```
sp|QBWMM1-2|PDCI_Mouse(741-770) 8864=mil (25/2.20/2.50)
sp|QBWMM1-2|PDCI_Mouse complex subunit alpha OS=Mouse OX=90009 PE=1 SV=1
```

the first part is the most important. they are considered similar because they have similar strings `sp|QBWMM1-2|PDCI_Mouse`

then I want to put them togther and it becomes

```
sp|QBWMM1-2|PDCI_Mouse complex subunit alpha OS=Mouse OX=90009 PE=1 SV=1 (741-770) 8864=mil (25/2.20/2.50)
```

So the output could be like this:

```
sp|QBWMM1-2|PDCI_Mouse complex subunit alpha OS=Mouse OX=90009 PE=1 SV=1 (741-770) 8864=mil (25/2.20/2.50)
sp|Pm345|Hisf_Mouse Heat shock 70 kDa protein 1A OS=Mouse OX=90009 PE=1 SV=1 (613-640) 776=mil (25/2.20/2.50))
sp|O15012|SCCC_Mouse Protein transport protein Sec16A OS=MOUSE OX=90009 PE=1 SV=4
sp|P0065-2|Hila_Mouse Filamin-A OS=MOUSE OX=90009 PE=1 SV=4 (344-393)6543=mil (25/2.20/2.50)
sp|Q90081|Rira_Mouse Alpha-actin OS=Mouse OX=90009 PE=1 SV=2 47-72) 7365=mil (25/2.20/2.50)
sp|QQQQQ1|Ubs_Mouse Tubulin alpha8 chain OS=Mouse OX=90009 PE=1 SV=1 (162-190) 22=mil (25/2.20/2.50)
sp|QQQQQ2|Ubs_Mouse Plasta-3 OS=Mouse OX=90009 PE=1 SV=4
```

Comment: What is sublime? Sublime Text? Then why the bash tag? I don't know "sublime", but probably you want to search for a tutorial on regular expressions.

Comment: @Sparhawk you are right, I updated my question to make it more comprehensive

Comment: You have totally changed the question with that edit! But the answer is using `join`. Hopefully you can use that to search for a tutorial, but it's fairly straightforward. Good luck.

Comment: join -a 1 text1.txt text2.txt does not give me the answer but thanks for your point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `file1` is your first text file, and `file2` is your second text file, this should work in Bash:

```
join -a 1 <(sort -k1,1 file2) <(sed -E -e 's/([^\s])\(/\1 (/' file1 | sort -k1,1)
```

`Join` is called with two files as arguments, which two files (anonymous pipes or FIFOs actually) are the result of two process substitutions that take the form `<(...)`in the above command.

The second argument file contains a modified version of `file1`, having a space inserted before the first `(` on each line so as to create a proper space-delimited join field; this modification is done by `sed`. The contents of both argument files are sorted based on the join field (i.e. field 1), as required by `join`. The `-a 1` option ensures that non-pairable lines in `file2` (i.e. the first argument file) are also output.